# Studio 1555 + Ubuntu drivers

Tags: wireless, drivers, ati, intel-graphics

I have Dell Studio 1555. 
I want to install Ubuntu. I have downloaded Ubuntu latest version(Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS) with 32 bit. there was an option with 64 bit (recommended). 
First question, Which version should I use? 
second question, from where I can get the drivers for the same?

Please help me out,

Thanks,
Jay

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on how much RAM your Dell contains. If it contains 2gb or less, than go with 32bit. But if it contains more than 2gb, say 4gb, than go for 64bit.

Minimal Drivers I **think** they will be installed automatically.

Have a good Ubuntu day :D

Comment: I have 4GB ram. But my machine with 32bit supported. So does it matter? or I just download ubuntu with 64bit and install it?

Comment: It will support 32bit, but according to what i have heard is it will use only 3gb of your ram, not 4gb. If you install 64bit then 4gb of your ram will used. You might want to search a bit more on google :).